# Purchased movies not available after first time played

Tags: icloud, appletv, itunes-store

I have purchased a movie and 20 minutes watching, I was ejected. When I tried to play it again, it seemed like the purchase never happened. I was asked to buy or rent it. It seems like I am not the only one. 
Is there anyone who had the same issue and solved the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem arises when I start my MacBook (Should be every computer that is connected to the same iTunes store account). If you avoid using it after the movie/documentary or anything else is streaming, you should not have the problem.

The solution is to sign out from your iTunes Store account and sign in, so rentals are restored. Just checking for rentals doesn't help.

Comment: Yes, simple solution but I don't know what it corrects exactly. Hope someone will :)